# Interpreting custom language

Tags: c#, antlr, interpreter, dsl

I need to develop an application that will read and understand text file in which I'll find a custom language that describe a list of operations (ie cooking recipe). This language has not been defined yet, but it will probably take one of the following shape :

- **C++ like code**

(This code is randomly generated, just for example purpose) :

```
begin
repeat(10)
{
    bar(toto, 10, 1999, xxx);
}
result = foo(xxxx, 10);
if(foo == ok)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
end
```

- **XML code**

(This code is randomly generated, just for example purpose) :

```
<recipe>
    <action name="foo" argument"bar, toto, xxx" repeat=10/>
    <action name="bar" argument"xxxxx;10" condition="foo == ok">
        <true>...</true>
        <false>...</false>
    </action>
</recipe>
```

No matter which language will be chosen, there will have to handle simple conditions, loops.

I never did such a thing but at first sight, it occurs to me that describing those operations into XML would be simplier yet less powerful.

After browsing StackOverFlow, I've found some chats on a tool called "ANTLR"... I started reading "The Definitive ANTLR Reference" but since I never done that kind of stuff, I find it hard to know if it's really the kind of tool I need...

In other words, what do I need to read a text file, interpret it properly and perform actions in my C# code. Those operations will interact between themselves by simple conditions like :

- If operation1 failed, I do operation2 else operation3.
- Repeat the operation4 10 times.

What would be the best language to do describe those text file (XML, my own) ? What are the key points during such developments ?

I hope I'm being clear :)

Thanks a lot for your help and advices !

Comment: I wouldn't say the XML is less powerful just more wordy.  Once the C++ language is parsed into an expression tree it could easily be turned into XML without loss of power.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid of encountering difficulties with loops, conditions, etc... As Moo-Juice said, I have trouble seeing XML as a language to describe logic... I see it more like a way of describin a static structre... Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML is great for storing relational data in a verbose way.  I think it is a terrible candidate for writing logic such as a program, however.

Have you considered using an existing grammar/scripting language that you can embed, rather than writing your own?  E.g:

[LUA](http://www.lua.inf.puc-rio.br/post/9)

[Python](http://ironpython.net/)

Comment: Can I use Python to create a DSL ? And eventually read the code, interpret it and call C# methods ?

Answer (score 2):

In one of my projects I actually started with an XML like language as I already had an XML parser and parsed the XML structure into an expression tree in memory to be interpreted/run.

This works out very nicely to get passed the problem of figuring out tokenizing/parsing of text files and concentrate instead on your 'language' and the logic of the operations in your language.  The down side is writing the text files is a little strange and very wordy. Its also very unnatural for a programmer use to C/C++ syntax.

Eventually you could easily replace your XML with a full blown scanner & lexer to parse a more 'natural C++' like text format into your expression tree.

As for writing a scanner & lexer, I found it easier to write these by hand using simple logic flow/loops for the scanner and recursive decent parser for the lexer.

That said, ANTLR is great at letting you write out rules for your language and generating your scanner & lexer for you.  This allows for much more dynamic language which can easily change without having to refactor everything again when new things are added. So, it might be worth looking into as learning this as it would save you much time in rewrites as things change if you hand wrote your own.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend writing the app in F#. It has many useful features for parsing strings and xmls like Pattern Matching and Active Patterns.

For parsing C-like code I would recommend F# (just did one interpreter with F#, works like a charm)

For parsing XML's I would recommend C#/F# + XmlDocument class.

You basically need to work on two files:

- Operator dictionary
- Code file in YourLanguage

Load and interpret the operators and then apply them recursively to your code file.

Answer (score 1):

The best prefab answer: [S-expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression)

C and XML are good first steps.  They have sort of opposite disadvantages.  The C-like syntax won't add a ton of extra characters, but it's going to be hard to parse due to ambiguity, the variety of tokens, and probably a bunch more issues I can't think of.  XML is relatively easy to parse and there's tons of example code, but it will also contain tons of extra text.  It might also give you too many options for where to stick language features - for example, is the number of times to repeat a loop an attribute, element or text?

S-expressions are more terse than XML for sure, maybe even C.  At the same time, they're specific to the task of applying operations to data.  They don't admit ambiguity.  Parsers are [simple and easy to find example code for](http://thingsaaronmade.com/blog/writing-an-s-expression-parser-in-ruby.html).

This might save you from having to learn too much theory before you start experimenting.  I'll emphasize MerickOWA's point that ANTLR and other parser generators are probably a bigger battle than you want to fight right now.  See [this discussion on programmers.stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17824/should-i-use-a-parser-generator-or-should-i-roll-my-own-custom-lexer-and-parser-c) for some background on when the full generality of this type of tool could help.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. Parsing C-like syntax is going to be too much trouble I think. I'll need to use ANTLR and I don't have the time to learn all this in the project I'm working on. S-expressions would be a good alternative but the source text to parse should be writeable by a non-computer scientist user. Therefore, I think I'll go with XML and a small application helping the user to write correct XML. What do you think ?