# Is there a way to place compilator in a program?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a game bot. I'd like to place there something like a scripter, my program is reading all the needed stuff from the game's memory and I've got all of game-objects. I'd like to add something to my program that allows user to make his own scripts.

eg.

```
foreach (character ch in characters_on_screen)
{
if (ch.burning()) {game_say("burning!");}
}
```

I don't really know if it's hard to make, thats why I'm writing here :P, I'm working in c# and the scripter language doesnt really matter I think, coz all the game scripts arent going to be hard i think
So whats the easiest way to do that? (if theres any)
Thanks :)

p.s.
I'd also like to know if there's a way to disable several functions, like creating files or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get the C# compiler to compile C# code *at runtime*. Check out the runtime compliation classes in the [`Microsoft.CSharp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.aspx) namespace.

There's also a tutorial [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/RuntimeCompilation.aspx).

This way you could attempt to santise the input if you so wish; it simply takes in strings. As well as imposing restrictions like implementing an interface.

Comment: thanks, Your answer seem to be the simplest one and that's what I've been looking for, im a newbie :P :)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [csscript](http://www.csscript.net/).

Answer (score 2):

There are several options you could go with.

1. If you want to create a really specialized scripting language, you'd basically have to implement one. That would require either creating semantical, lexical, syntactical analyzer that would translate your string input into a delegate chains.
2. Is you want to create a really specialized language without a fuss, you could search for existing frameworks.
3. You could use existing programming language to describe actions, like C# (and use Roslyn compiler), FreePascal, JS, Python/Ruby (and use DLR scripting engines to execute ruby/python code).

I'd personally go with python/ruby implementation. They're dynamic languages that have enough power and capability to be customized into a specific language.

You would probably also want to look at the following SO posts: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626999/interpreting-custom-language) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324904/extending-c-sharp-net-application-build-a-custom-scripting-language-or-not).

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with JavaScript. It's safer (eg. No filesystem access)  and easy to write for.  JavaScript .NET is a nice wrapper around the V8 engine.

There's also the `IActiveScript` COM interface that can be used to host any COM-based scripting language that implements IActiveScript (eg VBScript, JScript [both the older 5.x and the newer 9.x {Chakra}])

Comment: could You give me any link? :F :P is it free to commercial use?

Comment: easy to ask google for it, and I'm sure the project page will list its licensing requirements.